# Change default Index location of Search Service Instance on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, enterprise-search

My purpose is to move search index folder from drive C to drive D.

I've already changed location of all **search components** to drive D as described [here](https://itgroove.net/mmman/2015/01/11/sharepoint-2013-moving-the-search-index-partition-to-the-wfe/) and  [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142486/how-do-i-move-the-search-indexlocation-sharepoint-2013).

But The Default Index location of **Search Service Instance** is still located on drive C.

I know that cmdlet ***Set-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance*** has parameter ***-DefaultIndexLocation***. But this parameter is [obsolete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spenterprisesearchserviceinstance?view=sharepoint-ps) in SharePoint 2013, 2016,  2019.[image]

Now I have only one search topology and all components are located on drive D:
[image]

Search Service Instance configuration(Index location still located on drive C):
[image]

How can I move **Search Service Instance** Index Location to drive D without Search Service rebuilding?

The similar [post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35490a80-0caa-45b2-b40d-cc173e544fe3/moving-the-index-location-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral) without an answer.

[About](https://itgroove.net/mmman/2015/04/30/how-to-determine-your-sharepoint-2013-search-index-location-and-default-search-index-location/) The Default Search Index location.