# Journal taking all the space on C:\

Tags: space-usage

I have noticed today that C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Data\Office Server\Applications\Search\Nodes\E44938\IndexComponent1\storage\data\SP5337bd70a708.2.I.0.0\Journal taking all the space on C:. Can I delete these files?

Regards

[image]

Comment: Please help answering Harris' question, I have the same issue and I would like to find the root cause of those backupsection_ files and also I need to know if deleting them cause any issue

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/124105)

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the Search Index. See [How do I move the Search IndexLocation sharepoint 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142486/how-do-i-move-the-search-indexlocation-sharepoint-2013) for information on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, this issue I have is for some reason is creating backup files. Please see the screenshot.

Comment: Are you running `Backup-SPFarm` or running backups from Central Admin?

Comment: there is no backup running from CA.