# Journal index files

Tags: 2013, search, crawl, service, index

I have same issue described here:

[Journal taking all the space on C:\](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/279896/journal-taking-all-the-space-on-c/309264#309264)

Does anyone can tell if I delete those files, SP search/crawling will have issues after that?

Also, Do you know why those files are created?

Thanks